# EOFException while loading avro schema

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I am trying to load an avro schema file using maven.I have saved the avsc file in my classpath but I get EOFEception while a run it. I know the problem is the that the schema file could not be found because when I write the schema inside my code, it runs perfectly. I need some help please.Thanks in advance.

Here is the trace:

```
    [root@dev MapReduce]# hadoop jar target/MapReduce-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.hadoop.bi.MapReduce.AvroScTest StringPair.avsc
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2444)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2377)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:1234)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:1209)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:931)
    at org.apache.avro.Schema$Parser.parse(Schema.java:914)
    at com.hadoop.bi.MapReduce.AvroScTest.main(AvroScTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

and here is the code which I try to load the schema:

```
Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
Schema schema =parser.parse(AvroScTest.class.getResourceAsStream(args[0]));
```

here is the structure of project:

```
MapReduce
    src
      main
      test
    target
      classes
      MapReduce-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    pom.xml
    StringPair.avsc
```

schema content:

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "StringPair",
"doc": "A pair of strings.",
"fields": [
{"name": "left", "type": "string"},
{"name": "right", "type": "string"}
]
}
```

Comment: from the stack trace I see that json parsing failed, can you please post your "StringPair.avsc" file? is it located in correct place?

Comment: the schema looks correct, can you try to specify full file path when you give it to your job?

Comment: sorry I don't know what's the issue but I would print this in your code: `new File(args[0]).isFile()`. it would help to narrow down the issue

Comment: thanks @RomanI but I tested this and it was not the problem cause it passed the test.

Answer (score 0):

You can be sure about the `StringPair.avsc` file is in your jar by

```
mvn tf MapReduce-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

(If it's not listed maven can simply build it into the jar if you place it under the `src/main/resources/StringPair.avsc`)

For the "No content to map to Object due to end of input" error message the magic was for me to place a slash before the file name because it is in the root of the jar.

```
Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
Schema schema =parser.parse(AvroScTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/StringPair.avsc"));
```